# Links in Excel workbook not loading due to local google drive location

Tags: excel, vba

I originally posted this in SuperUser, but I think that may have been the wrong place, so I am cross posting it here.

-**Edit: The tag is Google-drive-sdk, but it's a problem with google drive in windows, not the api. I guess there's no option for google drive itself**

I have a master workbook which has links to about nine different files. I also have two other workbooks used by other people that link to the master workbook for information. All of these files are saved on google drive and everyone associated has access to all of the files individually. Up until yesterday there wasn't a problem with anyone loading the files, but now all of a sudden when opening the files on other computers, they can't find the links and can't load with the new information.

I'm assuming that part of the problem is due to me having google drive saved to my D:\ drive instead of C:\ like most of the other computers, and in my files the links all point to D:\google drive\, but as I said, it was all working up until yesterday.

Is there any way to work around this issue, without actually changing my drive location? I know I'm not the only person that has put google drive on a different partition than windows, so there is the potential for even that, causing conflicts.

Thank you for your help, and let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like a Drive API - specific inquiry, but I'll try to pitch in. I'm presuming you're using Google Drive for Windows (since you indicated the Google Drive is installed in D:), the location of the files referenced inside the workbook file would be absolute. You (and others) who installed the Drive app on D:\ wouldn't see the problem, but the others who installed it on the default location may have (which is what happened when you opened the files on other computers).

Check if you can set [relative paths instead of absolute paths](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) (same principle can be said on drive files), for example

```
D:\Google Drive\SharedFolder\Workbook01.xls
D:\Google Drive\SharedFolder\Workbook02.xls
D:\Google Drive\SharedFolder\Workbook02.xls
```

links referencing would be

```
Workbook01.xls
Workbook02.xls
Workbook03.xls
```

Hopefully this would help with the location issue.

Comment: I tried to edit the links in this manner, but the problem is they immediately reinstate the full file path. I then tried to just drop the Drive letter, which opened a File Explorer window to find the file. If I close that window, it defaults the link to C: which of course breaks the link on my own computer. I just did some more searching using your link and then similar searches in google, and perhaps the problem with this issue is that the files are not all located in the same folder? Unfortunately, moving them to the same folder is not an option.

Comment: It seems that excel now forces absolute paths, so even if you type it as a relative path, it will auto-fill the full path and when you save the file, it locks it in. Luckily I am no longer using the "Excel on google drive" system. Thank you for the input.